# Openshift privileges cluster managment

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools

Are there users with administrator privileges to handle cluster features (cluster management)?

How can I assign permissions to other users?

I would like to run the following command :

[root@localhost ~]# **oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user admin vittorio**

I get this error:

Error from server: User "system" cannot get clusterpolicybindings at the cluster scope

Comment: Where are you attempting to run that command? On the master node of the cluster? What do you get or ``oc whoami``? Does that user have admin role already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the bootstrap certificate based cluster admin user:

```
export KUBECONFIG=/path/to/openshift.local.config/master/admin.kubeconfig
oc whoami // should report system:admin
```